# How to add some keyword to regex_policy in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 carbon?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I added java script `alert` keyword to avoid accepting this keyword, but it's not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--
  ~  Copyright (c) 2017, WSO2 Inc. (http://wso2.com) All Rights Reserved.
  ~
  ~  WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
  ~  Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
  ~  in compliance with the License.
  ~  You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  ~  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  ~  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  ~  KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
  ~  specific language governing permissions and limitations
  ~  under the License.
  -->
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="regex_policy">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="IN_MESSAGE" value="Regular_expression_policy"/>
    </log>
    <property name="threatType" expression="get-property('threatType')" value="SQL-Injection"/>
    <property name="regex" expression="get-property('regex')" value=".*'.*|.*alter.*|.*alter \s*table.*|.*alter\s*view.*|
    .*create\s*database.*|.*create\s*procedure.*|.*create\s*schema.*|.*create\s*table.*|.*create\s*view.*|
    .*delete\s*from.*|.*drop\s*database.*|.*drop\s*procedure.*|.*drop\s*table.*|.*select\s*.*\s*from.*|
    .*truncate\s*table.*|.*insert\s*into.*|.*alert.*|.*alert*"/>
    <property name="enabledCheckBody" expression="get-property('checkBodyEnable')" value="true"/>
    <property name="enabledCheckHeaders" expression="get-property('enabledCheckHeaders')" value="true"/>
    <property name="enabledCheckPathParams" expression="get-property('enabledCheckPathParams')" value="true"/>
    <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.mediators.RegularExpressionProtector"/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Can you share the request payload which you have used to invoke the API and try out the scenario?

Comment: For example when I create api in /publisher I can store some keyword like "alert(1)" in data base and its security issue.

Comment: The Regex_policy which is attached to the question is used to protect the API invocations. However, it seems you are trying to create an API from the Publisher Portal and storing vulnerable commands. Please correct if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Yes you're right. Could please guide me ?